# Do the derivatives of a moment generating function evaluated at 0 uniquely determine the distribution of a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I understand that the moment generating function of a random variable uniquely determines that random variable. And that for an rv X, M(0)=1, M'(0)=E[X], M''(0)=E[X^2],... and so on.

My question is that if M'(0)=E[X] gives the general form of the expectation of say, a gamma random variable, then does that imply that X follows a gamma distribution?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's true that if X has the same expectation as a gamma random variable then X has a gamma distribution?

Comment: Essentially yes. And if the answer is no, would it be confirmed by the expectation and the variance being the same?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then your claim could be disproved with a constant random variable. And you can always match the mean and variance with a non gamma distribution, e.g., a normal.